# Finding the time until 3 points that move with different speed overlap again

Tags: elementary-number-theory, physics

I have three belts that run over two wheels. [image]

Due to individual characteristics, the time for one turn, $x_i$, differs between the belts. Before starting the system, each belt is marked at the same spot (red dot). The system will stop once the position of the marked spots overlaps again (anywhere). The aim is to predict the runtime of the system only knowing the speed of the belts.

I don't really know how to solve this problem. My thoughts so far where to regard the system as a collection of three interval with length $x_i$ (representing the speed of the corresponding belt) times a constant $\alpha_i$ (representing the number of turns) and then estimate $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ by the least common multiple of $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$. But this attempt quickly turned out to be a fallacy because it ignores the "repeating character" of the system.

Now I feel quite at loss. I guess this is a (common) problem in physics/mechanics but I don't have any buzzword or anything. Any ideas?

Comment: We need more info. What are the lengths of the three belts? You've given us variables for speed, but we need info on the lengths of the belts to do the calculation.

Comment: let's just call the lengths $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$ and $\ell_3$. 

How are the lengths important? I thought everything is already covered by the time to complete one turn

Comment: No it's not, because they don't necessarily line up at the same point, no?

Comment: well, actually I got confused by your comment (and maybe I did not make that clear enough in my original post): of course all belts must have the same length! What is dashed in my diagram should indicate a belt

Comment: In that case, you can simply do LCM of $\frac{\textrm{length}}{\textrm{speed}}$ for each speed, and the LCM is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not the periods $x_i$, but the differences of the speeds $v_i$ have to be commensurable.

Let $0<v_1<v_2<v_3$ be the speeds of the belts, and $\ell$ their common length. The first time $t$ when the red dots on the first two belts coincide again is when the red dot on the second belt is lapping the red dot on the first belt. This means that
$v_2 t=v_1 t+\ell$, or
$$t={\ell\over v_2-v_1}=:t_2\ .$$
Henceforth the marks on these two belts coincide at all integer multiples of $t_2$. Similarly, the marks on the first and the third belt coincide at all integer multiples of
$$t_3:={\ell\over v_3-v_1}\ .$$ We shall see a coincidence of all three marks (after $t=0$) iff the two numbers $t_2$, $t_3$ are commensurable, i.e. iff there are integers $q>p\geq1$ (in lowest terms) such that $$t_*:=pt_2=qt_3\ .$$ This is the case iff
$${p\over q}={v_2-v_1\over v_3-v_1}\ .$$
If this condition is fulfilled  all three marks coincide for the first time (after $t=0$) at time $t_*\>$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! The only thing I could not understand is how you got to $v_2t = v_1t + \ell$. Assuming (just for now) that the length of the belts differed, what would be the formula then?

Comment: The belts must have the same velocity, sharing the same two pulleys. This is supported by the “phrase $speed$ vs $speeds$ of the belts.” The question also does not say that the belts have a common length and physics suggests that they must not. Rather, they ‘do’ go over the same two pulleys but may also engage additional pulleys, much like the different ‘fan belts’ in a car may use more than two pulleys. Having the same velocity, it takes different times for different belts to complete a circuit. The time for all three to complete the circuit can be found using the LCM method I  suggested.

Comment: @poetasis: The setup is not described in a clear cut way.  I treated the problem as I understood it. A general rule in such cases is "Occam's razor": Make the minimal assumptions supported by the givens.

Comment: To me, Occam's razor demands that I picture what must be reality for different belts to take different times going around the same two  pulleys. It cannot be done without slippage or different lengths. Yes, it could be like slipping fan belts–some take longer make the circuit–but it's simpler to think of different belt lengths. BTW @Syd Amerikaner, did my answer make sense or not?